# Button reference in Qt from different function

Tags: c++, qt

Currently, I'm working on a project in Qt that has multiple buttons and text boxes that share functionality.

For example:

```
void SettingsMenu::on_normalTextColor_clicked()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::yellow, this);
    if(color.isValid())
    {
        QString qss = QString("background-color: %1").arg(color.name());
        ui->normalTextColor-setStyleSheet(qss);
    }
    ui->normalTextHex->setText(color.name());
}
```

In this case, `normalTextColor` corresponds to a button which, if clicked creates a color dialogue, then sets the color of that button to the selected color and sets the text in `normalTextHex` to the hex code of the selected color (iff that color is valid).  My other buttons and boxes follow an identical name structure, with the buttons being [someLabel]Color and the boxes being [someLabel]Hex.

Since I have over 20 of these buttons to hook up, I was thinking to make a single function that I could reference, rather than writing out all the code every single time.  I thought that by passing the name of the button as a string and then appending to it I could reference that in the overarching function.

For example:

```
void SettingsMenu::SetColorOfButton(QString temp)
{
    QString tempColor = temp.Append("Color");
    QString tempHex = temp.Append("Hex");
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::yellow, this);
    if(color.isValid())
    {
        QString qss = QString("background-color: %1").arg(color.name());
        ui->tempColor->setStyleSheet(qss);
    }
    ui->tempHex->setText(color.name());
}
```

This results in an error:

> 'no member named `tempColor` in `Ui::SettingsMenu`'

I understand that this is because 'ui->[someName]' call does not merely take a string, but a reference to an object.

However, even if I pass the `PushButton` object as a pointer to the `SetColorOfButton` function, I am unable to set the color of the **actual** button because I currently am looking at a pointer to that button.

So how would I reference a series of buttons whose names I do not know at runtime from a function?

Comment: ***So how would I reference a series of buttons whose names I do not know at runtime from a function?*** Maybe use findChildren<QPushButton*>() on the parent widget?

Comment: The overarching parent class is SettingsMenu (A QWidget).  Calling "QPushButton *meButton = SettingsMenu->findChild<QPushButton *>(tempColor); results in the following error: 'SettingsMenu' does not refer to a value'

Comment: In my opinion you could make simpler and more robust code by creating a custom QWidget composed of a button and a text (in a layout), that handles the change of color (both background and hex text) in a slot connected to the `clicked` signal of the button. Then you could create as many instances of this custom widget as you want in your GUI. This is more modular than your solution. Downside is that you need to configure something to use the custom widget in QtDesigner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  The resulting function will display the desired functionality outlined above.

```
void SettingsMenu::SetColorOfButton(QString temp)
{
    QString tempColor = temp.append("Color");
    temp.chop(5);
    QString tempHex = temp.append("Hex");
    QPushButton *tempPushButton = findChild<QPushButton*>(tempColor);
    QTextEdit *tempTextEdit = findChild<QTextEdit*>(tempHex);

    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::yelow, this);
    if(color.isValid())
    {
        QString qss = QString("background-color: %1").arg(color.name());
        tempPushButton->setStyleSheet(qss);
    }
    tempTextEdit->setText(color.name());
}
```

Thanks to drescherjm for the assistance.  I didn't understand the functionality of findchild() as well as I thought I did.

Comment: pass temp byconst reference instead of by copy